# Creating a userlist in Views (including custom user fields)

Tags: views, users

I've encountered an issue using Views 3 in Drupal 7. 
I want to create a user list with a bunch of fields I added to the user profile (using Drupal's core user fields). I need a list of **all** users, and right now I keep getting the currently created content and its author (with the appropriate user fields). Not all users have created content.

I've created a relationship "Content: Author" to get access to the custom user fields, but that's not the reason I keep getting the content with its author. I get the same result when I remove the relationship and custom user fields.

In Drupal 6 with views2 I made the same page and had no issues. Could this perhaps be a bug in Views 3, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question makes it sound like you've created a node view, listing content. If you create a view listing *users*, you should be able to accomplish what you're trying here.
[image]

Comment: Oh snap, I didn't notice that option whilst creating the view. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is it possible to change the "Show" after one has created a view? Or am I forced to make a completely new view?

Answer (score 0):

You can now get a better administrative users list by installing the [Administrative Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.