# A module to add a field for display as a column in the administration area

Tags: theming

I would like to display a column with the email address to the listing of users in my site's administration area. does anyone know of a module that does this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't easily extend that list directly.

The easiest way is to replace the default user list using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and probably [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).

See also [Creating a userlist in Views (including custom user fields)](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4398/creating-a-userlist-in-views-including-custom-user-fields).